# How to assign result (from LINQ to XML query) to List(Of string)?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

Is it wrong? Please suggest me  correct way.

```
Public Function ReadXML() As List(Of String)

    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\\MappingFile.xml")

    Dim q = From c In xmlDoc.Descendants("Entity") 
            Where c.Attribute("Source").Value = "E_cdclient"
            Select New With {
                 .source = c.Elements("Property").Attributes("Source"),  //This is one collection
                 .target = c.Elements("Property").Attributes("Target")   //This is another collection.
             }

    list = q    **//Here I am getting error.**
    Return list
End Function
```

**Here is my XML.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Entities>
  <Entity Source="E_cdclient" Target="cd_client">
    <Property Source="KnowledgeItemId" Target="CLIENT_CONTACT_ID"/>
    <Property Source="KnowledgeClientID" Target="CLIENT_CONTACT_ID"/>
  </Entity>
  <Entity Source="E_cdclientsystem" Target="cd_client_system">
    <Property Source="PrimaryKnowledgeItemId" Target="0"/>
    <Property Source="RelatedKnowledgeId" Target="0"/>
  </Entity>
  <Entity Source="E_cdclient_cdclientcontact" Target="cd_client_contact">
    <Property Source="shortdescription" Target="analysis_short_description"/>
    <Property Source="OWNERID" Target="REF_PROJECT_OWNER_ID"/>
  </Entity>
  <Entity Source="E_cdclient_cdquestiontype" Target="cd_questiontype">
    <Property Source="" Target="analysis_short"/>
    <Property Source="" Target="analysis_sho"/>
  </Entity>
</Entities>
```

Thanks,
JN

Comment: What should the resulting list contain? It's a list of strings, but you're trying to assign a collection of (anonymous) objects to it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know VB but I think if it was in c# u had to convert it to list so at the end of your LINQ query you must do something like this (your LINQ query).toList();

By the way you are returning (anonymous) objects and you want to assing it to the list of string but returned type can not be string because it is actually object with tow properties